Registering 32 bit COM Dll as part of a GitHub Actions Pipeline
I am trying to use github actions to deploy a dotnet app which has a dependency on at 32 bit COM Dll.
I register the DLl with RegSvr32, which seems to work. (I do not get an exception)
but then I get the following exception during the build:
Run msbuild path/to/my.csproj /p:Configuration=Release
MSBuild version 17.11.9+a69bbaaf5 for .NET Framework
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3040,5): warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "0a67e301-3ecb-47be-bba9-dc67ff219358" version 1.0. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))

Apparently the component also needs a Type Library to work. It's either a standalone file (usually a .tlb) or it's embedded into a binary (.dll, etc.) as a Win32 resource (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/automat/registering-a-type-library). It's the COM object vendor who is reponsible for registering this type library. It's usually done at the same time as the COM object itself (when DllRegisterServer is called which is what regsvr32 does). You should contact the vendor.

In my case the dll was all that was required.

What worked for me was copying the dll to SysWow Directory:
- name: Copy DLL to SysWoW64
  run: |
    $dllPath = "${{ github.workspace }}\path\to\dllName.dll"
    $destinationPath = "$env:SystemRoot\SysWoW64\dllName.dll"
    Copy-Item -Path $dllPath -Destination $destinationPath -Force
    if (Test-Path $destinationPath) {
      Write-Output "DLL copied to $destinationPath"
    } else {
      Write-Error "Failed to copy DLL to $destinationPath"
      exit 1
    }


- name: Register COM DLL (32-bit)
  run: |
    $dllPath = "$env:SystemRoot\SysWoW64\DllName.dll"
    $outputFile = "${{ github.workspace }}\regsvr32_output.txt"
    Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe" -ArgumentList "/s", $dllPath -Wait -NoNewWindow -PassThru | Out-File $outputFile
    $exitCode = $LastExitCode
    Get-Content $outputFile

As an aside, you have to use  msbuild if the project is referencing a COM dll.
- name: Set up MSBuild
  uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1

# other steps ...

- name: Build and Publish
  run: msbuild path/to/ProjectName.csproj /t:Publish /p:Configuration=Release /p:OutputPath=./publish

